# Run script over ssh could not connect to the ssh server

Tags: windows, networking, ssh, iphone, ios

I am trying to open an application on my windows(SSH server) via iPhone (SSH Client).[image]
[I keep getting this error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1B8g.png)

1. I tried changing host to PCNAME.local did not work
2. I tried changing host to IPv4 Address also did not work.
3. I tried using local username did not work
4. I tried using Microsoft account email address(linked to my windows) did not work.
5. I tried using local Pin windows code did not work.
6. I tried using Microsoft account password did not work.
7. opening port 22 in firewall inbound rules
8. Turns out the problem is with the hostname. When typing the local IPV4 address(192.168. . ), the ssh command can be committed/executed. When entering **external IPV4 address** OR ***my_host_name*.local**, SSH client can't connect to the ssh server. What could be the problem?

[I keep getting this errorr message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1B8g.png)
What could be that problem? BTW I am not that competent with SSH so be easy with me.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).

Comment: You might want to try that from another client machine or to another SSH server to tell if it's the server's or the client's fault.

Comment: Turns out the problem is with the hostname. When typing the local IPV4 address(192.168. . ), the ssh command can be committed/executed. When entering external IPV4 address OR my_host_name.local, SSH client can't connect to the ssh server. What could be the problem?

Comment: You may have some remote DNS server configured in your iPhone which does not know local hosts. And you may have forgotten to configure your PCNAME as exposed host or port in your router which is necessary for the PCNAME to be reachable using the external IP.

Comment: that's right i have adguard dns server turned on. I will check later to see if this is the problem